# Dirichlets theorem on primes

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Is there a proof of dirichlets theorem that does not require complex analysis?

Comment: I don't know, but I can't see how to dispose of Dirichlet (complex) characters...Besides this, complex analysis is very beautiful and useful stuff, and Dirichlet's Theorem's proof is very nice...with complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof given in *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland and Rosen doesn't use anything you wouldn't learn outside of say a basic calculus course.

Comment: Can I get a link to the proof somehow?

Comment: Its a copyrighted book, so I believe an online copy of the book is illegal. However, you can buy a copy here : http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Introduction-Modern-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/038797329X. You can probably borrow this book from a local university's library, I'd be very surprised if the library lacked a book as famous as this.