# Proof of Dirichlet's theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I was reading David M. Burton's *Elementary number theory* a few months ago. They mentioned Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions (without proof) which states:

> There are infinitely many primes in any arithmetic progression.

I thought, since they said it, that the proof would be very advanced, so I didn't search for a proof. But now, I have (almost) mastered elementary number theory, and I can understand analysis, analytic number theory and algebraic number theory.
So please give a proof of Dirichlet's theorem. I have given my background, so please give a proof that I can understand. If the proof is too long for this site, please link an article containing the proof.
I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842300/is-there-no-proof-of-dirichlets-results-on-quadratic-residues-without-analysis) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259673/dirichlets-theorem-on-primes) question, but they didn't answer my question, so I wish my answer doesn't get closed.
Note: [Here](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2017/REUPapers/WangZijian.pdf) is a proof, but I want more proofs.

Comment: This is a classical subject covered in several textbooks. Did you check the references on the Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: The proof you linked seems reasonably straightforward, as it's contained in a 13-page document. Could you please explain further why you need more proofs, and what kind of proofs?

Comment: I want more proofs, it's just because of curiosity. I have mentioned my background, so I want a proof considering it.

Comment: Just look up analytic number theory books or online notes and you will find plenty of versions of proofs. Why do you need help finding proofs of this theorem when essentially all widely used introductory analytic number theory texts will have a proof?

Comment: The proof of this theorem is not easy , "elementary" does not mean easy. If others have no problem to follow the usual proofs, OK, I am honest enough to admit I could not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a nice proof for Dirichlet Theorem in this [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387724898)